# How to resolve $ls comparison error with Date within a mongo find javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to query a mongo collection (called Device) with documents containing a field called `LastUpdateTime`, which is type Date. Using Javascript, I'd like to query all active devices and retrieve all documents that have a last update time of at least 2 hours. This is how I'm currently doing this, where in the mongo find I'm getting all times less than the time now - an environment variable called `TIME_WINDOW`, which is currently set to 2hrs (it will always be in hrs). When I do this I get the error `Error: Can't use $ls with Date.`. The property `LastUpdateTime` is type Date. Is there another way to use $ls to perform this find?

```
        let rightNow = new Date();
        let timeWindow = rightNow.setHours(rightNow.getHours() - parseInt(process.env.TIME_WINDOW.trim()));
        const devices = await Device.find({Status : "Active", LastUpdateTime: {$ls: rightNow}});
```

Any ideas what is getting me the error `Error: Can't use $ls with Date.` or how I might be able to go about doing this find differently? I believe there's a way to do this based on other Stack Overflow posts, but not sure why I'm getting this error. Any advice would help!

Comment: Where is the `$ls` operator coming from?

Comment: mongodb does not have any `$ls` operator. where did you get this?

Comment: You can try using some of these [MongoDB Query Comparison Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#comparison).

Comment: Thanks very much. I was using `$ls` rather than `$lt`. When I use `$lt`, it's working